# Reading from binary file

Tags: java, serialization

I have written the data into binary file.But i dont know how to read from binary file. For writing i have account number, username ,password, name to write into binary file as below:

```
  LinkedHashMap<String, String> details = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
               details.put("Acount Number", "1986940573948");
               details.put("Username", "Krischal");
               details.put("Password", "8749578679");
               details.put("Name","Krischal mahat");

      String filename="dataFiles\\Customers.dat"; 

  addCustomer (filename, details.values(), true);

  public static void addCustomer (String filename, Collection col, boolean append){
      File file = new File (filename);
      ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    String str;
      try{
          if (!file.exists () || !append) out = new ObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream (filename));
          else out = new AppendableObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream (filename, append));
          Iterator itr = col.iterator();
          while (itr.hasNext()) {
               str = (String) itr.next();
               out.writeObject(str);
          }
          out.writeObject("\n");              
          out.flush ();
      }catch (Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace ();
      }finally{
          try{
              if (out != null) out.close ();
          }catch (Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace ();
          }
      }
  }
```

Please someone help me to read data of customer by giving the account number of that customer from binary file. Ihave used following code to read .But its showing errors. I just want to display all data of customer by providing account number.

```
 public static void check (String filename){
      File file = new File (filename);

      if (file.exists ()){
          ObjectInputStream ois = null;
          try{
              ois = new ObjectInputStream (new FileInputStream (filename));
              while (true){
                  String s = (String)ois.readObject ();
                  System.out.println (s);
              }
          }catch (EOFException e){

          }catch (Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace ();
          }finally{
              try{
                  if (ois != null) ois.close();
              }catch (IOException e){
                  e.printStackTrace ();
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: That file doesn't look like it would be very binary.  Is there any reason why you wouldn't just write/read it in a common format like json or xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Binary' and 'line by line' are mutually contradictory. Make up your mind. You're using `writeObject()`, which means binary, and Serialization, and you shouldn't be writing line terminators at all. You just need to use `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` to read this file.

You don't need to iterate, either. Just write the whole collection object. Or indeed the entire `Map`, every time, without appending.